# Как перезаписать созданный текстовый файл в RichTextBox в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Тут я опишу вопрос подробнее. Есть 3 кнопки: Одна отвечает за сохранение в новый текстовый файл, вторая за сохранение в уже созданный файл, а третья за загрузку из файла. Так вот, меня интересует как сохранить текст в уже созданный файл. Вот картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Извиняюсь если похожий вопрос существовал, а я его не заметил. Заранее спасибо.
Код первой кнопки:

```
        private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|RichText Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf|XAML Files (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            TextRange doc = new TextRange(docBox.Document.ContentStart, docBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(sfd.FileName))
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName).ToLower() == ".rtf")
                    doc.Save(fs, DataFormats.Rtf);
                else if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName).ToLower() == ".txt")
                    doc.Save(fs, DataFormats.Text);
                else
                    doc.Save(fs, DataFormats.Xaml);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Картинка про одно, код про другое, рассказ про третье.

Comment: Ну вот так уж получилось. Извиняюсь

Comment: Непонятно, на что здесь отвечать.

Comment: Перефразировать?

Comment: Давайте максимально конкретную задачу, вашу попытку ее реализовать в виде кода и описание сути проблемы, что именно не получилось, и ничего лишнего. А то про 3 кнопки, которые здесь явно не при чем, я не понял.

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы в диалоге при нажатии на txt файл и нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" содержание этого txt файла изменялось, и не вылетало сообщение, которое было в картинке. Надеюсь будет понятней

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog ответ в документации, которую всегда надо читать

Comment: Просмотрел несколько раз, подскажите, что именно?

Comment: Серьезно? _CheckFileExists Получает или задает значение, указывающее, отображает ли диалоговое окно открытия или сохранения файла предупреждение, если пользователь указал несуществующее имя файла._

Comment: Так я думал "несуществующее имя файла" не равно "имя существующего файла"

Comment: Я использовал OverwritePromt вместо этого, и оно работает.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что дали верный путь к решению